# how to concanate str with a list

Tags: python, error-handling

```
elem_1 = ['Hydrogen', 'Helium'] 
elem_2 = ['Lithium', 'Beryllium', 'Boron', 'Carbon', 'Nitrogen', 'Oxygen', 'Fluorine', 'Neon']
elem_3 = ['Sodium', 'Magnesium', 'Aluminum', 'Silicon', 'Phosphorus', 'Sulfur', 'Chlorine', 
'Argon']
print("Row 1:" + elem_1)
print("Row 2:" + elem_2)
print("Row 3:" + elem_3)
```

Right now it gives `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str`

I want the output to look like this:

```
Row 1: Hydrogen, Helium
Row 2: Lithium, Beryllium, Boron, Carbon, Nitrogen, Oxygen, Fluorine, Neon
Row 3: Sodium, Magnesium, Aluminum, Silicon, Phosphorus, Sulfur, Chlorine, Argon
```

Comment: i.e. you need to convert the list to a string, and then you can concatenate two strings

Comment: @Anentropic [No *need*](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PzUnNTfeSMFWIVrdJ7MkI7M0V11HQd0ptagyJwfGyS/KzwMxnBOLkiAsv8ySovz0VDDbv6ISynLLKc0vysxLBatIBaqM5eIqAAqUaKTmpdiqB@WXKxhZKahrQgW1IHbrKBSnFtiC9Gj@/w8A) to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Use `join`

```py
print("Row 1: " + ', '.join(elem_1))
print("Row 2: " + ', '.join(elem_2))
print("Row 3: " + ', '.join(elem_3))
```

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

> **str.join(iterable)**
>
> Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in iterable.

Answer (score 1):

In versions of python 3.6 and higher you can use f-strings.
Then you can evaluate code within curly brackets

```py
print(f"Row 1: {','.join(elem_1)}")
```

Other types of string interpolation can be found in

https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/